# Gitlab-Runner on Kubernetes with Self-Hosted Gitlab - issues with Connecting to Docker host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

Could you help me to resolve my issues with K8s + Gitlab Runner.

I have installed gitlab-runner with Helm ,
Here is the part of my values.yaml :

```
gitlabUrl: *****
runnerRegistrationToken: ******

certsSecretName: gitlab-cert

config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "ubuntu:22.04"
        tag = "development-test"
        privileged = true
        [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
          [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.secret]]
            name = "gitlab-cert"
            mount_path = "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/"
            read_only = true
          [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
            name = "docker-socket"
            path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
            mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
            read_only = false
          [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
            name = "docker-config"
            path = "/path/to/your/docker/config"  # Specify the actual path on your host
            mount_path = "/etc/docker"
            read_only = true
```

Everything looks good, and gitlab runner has deployed successfully without errors and it's connected to my Gitlab.

```
image: amazoncorretto:17

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone


stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy


# maven-test:
#   stage: test
#   script:
#     - echo "Running test data..."
#     - ./mvnw validate

maven-build-image-prod:
  only:
    - main
    - Dev
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: 'tcp://localhost:2375'
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  
  services:
  - name: docker:19.03-dind
    entrypoint: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh", "--tls=false"]
  script:
    - echo "Building image to container registry..."
    - ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image 
  tags:
    - development-test

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - mkdir ~/.kube/
    - echo $KUBE_CONFIG_PROD | base64 -d > config
    - mv config ~/.kube/
  script:
    - echo "Deploying new container image to production server"
    - curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
    - install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    - kubectl version --client
    - CONTAINER_VERSION=$(awk -F'[<>]' '/<artifactId>kompanyon<\/artifactId>/{getline; print $3}' pom.xml)
    - echo "CONTAINER_VERSION"    
    - sed -i 's|\${containerversion}|'"$CONTAINER_VERSION"'|' k8s/deployment.yaml
    - kubectl get nodes 
    #- kubectl apply -f k8s/deployment.yaml

  only:
    - main
  tags:
    - production

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - mkdir ~/.kube/
    - echo $KUBE_CONFIG | base64 -d > config
    - mv config ~/.kube/
  script:
    - echo "Deploying new container image to development server"
    - curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
    - install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    - kubectl version --client
    - CONTAINER_VERSION=$(awk -F'[<>]' '/<artifactId>kompanyon<\/artifactId>/{getline; print $3}' pom.xml)
    - echo "CONTAINER_VERSION"    
    - sed -i 's|\${containerversion}|'"$CONTAINER_VERSION"'|' k8s/deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f k8s/deployment.yaml

  only:
    - Dev
  tags:
    - development-test
```

it gives me an error :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) on project kompanyon: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost:2375' failed with error "Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible -> [Help 1]

I have Kubernetes cluster where Gitlab-Runner works in gitlab-runner namespace.
Really don't understand how to solve this problem!

WIll be very appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: 'tcp://localhost:2375'
```

You need to use socket connection to the docker daemon, not via TCP.
In your `gitlab-runner` you have specified the path to it.

Please take a look [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-docker-socket-binding), there are examples for both TCP and SOCKET.

P.S. I do not use docker for building images, using `podman` instead. It doesn't need docker.socket for work.

Comment: I tried to start pipeline without this DOCKER_HOST, but I have the same error , can't connect to localhost:2375

Comment: Updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: Just to add. Another alternative to building without using docker socket is `kaniko` and GitLab also provide examples for that here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html

Comment: `kaniko` can't build multi-arch images, as for me it's now mandatory requirement